# How do automatically generated instance variables work in NSManagedObjects?

Tags: xcode, core-data, dynamic, nsmanagedobject, synthesize

Xcode 4.5 and later auto-synthesizes properties, making an instance variable with the underscore prepended on the property name. But how does this work in an NSManagedObject? They want you to use KVC primitive methods in your custom setters. So what happens if you set an instance variable via the underscore ivar inside the NSManagedObject? Won't that screw things up since it would bypass the KVC methods? Or is it safely doing this behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

If you access the underscore instance variable directly, you are bypassing the work that `NSManagedObject` does for you. You should use the **get and set accessor methods** that NSManagedObject auto-generates for your attributes.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001803-CJBDBHCB) states

> When you access or modify properties of a managed object, you should
>   use these [accessor] methods directly.

You can implement your own accessor methods if required, but in that case, you have to do additional work beyond changing the value of the instance variable:

> You must ensure that you invoke the relevant access and change
>   notification methods (willAccessValueForKey:, didAccessValueForKey:,
>   willChangeValueForKey:, didChangeValueForKey:,
>   willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:, and
>   didChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:).

This should illustrate that you can't get the correct behavior simply by modifying the instance variable directly.

Comment: I understand all this. But can the getter for one dynamic property set another dynamic property with the underscore ivar as long as it wraps line of code in these relevant access and change notification methods?

Comment: Why would a getter act as a setter for a different attribute? That's an unusual side-effect. And why not use the auto-generated setter method?

Answer (score 0):

Note that unlike ordinary properties, `NSManagedObject` properties are not synthesized at compile time (hence the use of `@dynamic` for the implementation). Since compile-time synthesis isn't used, there are no synthesized instance variables available for you to set.

Instead, instances of `NSManagedObject` have a private internal instance of something similar to an `NSMutableDictionary` to store their state. The dynamically generated property accessors are wrappers for calls to KVC-like methods that access the private storage.